# Is there a way I can make nodemon to skip a snippet of code in app.js to run everytime I hit save?

Tags: node.js

I am using nodemon to restart my node server automatically after every save, however I don't want it to make DB connection everytime I save the code.
I tried Db connection code to move in separate "dbconnection.js" file and in package.json I edited the "start" script as "node dbconnection.js && nodemon app.js", but it only makes database connection and execution don't reach to app.js.

Comment: Yes, it's called commenting out the code.

Answer (score -1):

you can achieve that using environment variables and ask if that variable is assigned.